# ANTLR Android log grammar. Parsing application parameters

Tags: android, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to parse Android log system file. Everything is going OK but it doesn't work when I try to parse parameters from log content. My grammar which provides parsing log content

> logcontent
>   :
>   (
>   parameter|text|SPECIALCHAR|DIGIT|MINUS|EQUAL|COLON|DOT|APOSTROPHE|LEFTBRACKET|RIGHTBRACKET|SLASH|'_'|WS
>   )+;
>
> parameter
>       :   text+ EQUAL (integer|floatnumber|exponentfloat)
>       ;

Parameter has text inside the rule so ANTLR says that grammar is ambiguous.
I tried with a different rule definitions but it doesn't work. I'd like to parse this fragment of log

> acquireWakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG uid=1000 pid=373

How can I get whole log in string format and list of pairs 'parameter = value'

> flags=0x2000000a
>
> tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG
>
> uid=1000
>
> pid=373

Comment: I don't think ANTLR is the right tool for this job, not that it can't do it, I just don't think it is the best tool.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using regular expressions for this task instead. It's faster and simpler for this type of operation.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)=(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String value = matcher.group(2);
    // do whatever here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It realy helped me.